# No Monte-Carlo tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I was answering [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/421836/why-does-it-become-difficult-to-sample-configuration-during-a-phase-change-in-mo) and saw that it was tagged [molecular-dynamics] which surprised me, since it is nothing to do with MD. I thought I would edit it to include the tag [Monte-Carlo], only to find that it doesn't exist. That surprised me more. Although I can understand that some questions about Monte Carlo simulation might be better suited to [Computational Science SE](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/), or even conceivably Math or Stats SE, many such questions are intimately connected with the physics of the system, and would be a good fit here (IMHO). I can't find much serious discussion of this here on Meta.

If I finally get up to the reputation level needed to create new tags, and attempt to create [Monte-Carlo], should I expect some counter-arguments?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Concerning questions about Monte-Carlo, they should first of all be tagged with the [computational-physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computational-physics) tag and possibly the [simulations](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/simulations) tag.
- Whether a new tag [X] should be introduced depends on various factors, such as, e.g.,

  1. Nearby tags: each question can only support 5 tags.
  2. Are people actual going to use the [X] tag, or is it just collecting dust? If tag [X] is only applied on, say, 10% of all subject X questions, it may be more fruitful to search for the word X directly, rather than to search for a tag [X].
  3. The interests of the Phys.SE community is not uniformly distributed over all physics topics. Certain areas of physics may call for more refined tagging than others.
  4. Phys.SE is user-driven. If a user volunteer to be a curator for a new tag [X], it is more likely to be realized.
- Reminder to everyone: If you see errors in a post (such as, e.g. a tag that doesn't belong), you are encouraged to edit/leave a comment, whichever seems most appropriate (and provided the main original intent of the post is not altered).